# Synonym for an evil object?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is a there a noun that means an object that is 'evil' or is anti-life? I am looking for a word to characterize a bullet that killed an innocent person.
I have found some adjectives such as [heinous](https://www.google.com/#q=heinous+definition), [atrocious](https://www.google.com/#q=atrocious+definition), [nefarious](https://www.google.com/#q=nefarious+definition), and [malevolent](https://www.google.com/#q=malevolent+definition) that can accurately describe the bullet, but I am looking for a noun. Characterizing the whole shooting as an atrocity is another solution, but I am looking for a word that is more of an object than an act. Thanks for all help

For example:

> The bullet is nothing but a _______

Comment: @Jon If you read the tooltip, it mentions a lack of [evident research](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/talisman) as a reason for a downvote. (That link is not ideal, but it's better than nothing).

Comment: There are people who will tell you that a bullet is nothing but a hunk of lead (and guns don't kill people, people do).  What "spin" do you want to put on this word?

Comment: Look for synonyms for "evil" as a noun: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/evil

Comment: I disagree that you can use *malevolent* as an adjective describing the bullet. *Malevolent* suggest agency, which bullets don't possess. Your other adjectives do seem to work though (although *nefarious bullet* also sounds a bit of to me).

Comment: @NVZ I'm struggling for a one-word applicable noun that encapsulates the intent. There are some good adjectives here - and the answers aren't terrible as nouns go, but they can't capture the emotion without further context. *The obscene lead* is fine when you know that it's just killed someone; *bane* isn't strong enough in the sense of "something recently fatal" (c/f your telephone example - hardly fatal!).

Comment: *res mala* is a Latin phrase meaning "evil thing". It's highfalutin and non-English, but you might get away with it as a loan.

Comment: Scope out "deodand", lit. "offered/given to God", if you wanna get archaic. Specifically means the object used to murder, iirc. (Not evil, as intrinsic, but as the use it was put to.)

Answer (score 2):

***obscenity***

> The bullet is nothing but an obscenity.

This is a word an anguished relative or friend of the innocent victim might use as she/he rails against the immediate cause of the victim's death.

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obscenity), an **obscenity** is something that is obscene.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscene) has as one of its definitions of **obscene**

> abominable; disgusting; repulsive

Answer (score 2):

"The bullet is nothing but a *curse* (or *abomination*)"

**Curse** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curse)

> *noun* 1.1 *(usually in singular)* A cause of harm or misery
>
> <sub><sup>***synonyms*** evil, blight, scourge, plague, cancer, canker, poison</sup></sub>

**Abomination** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abomination)

> *noun* 1. A thing that causes disgust or loathing
>
> <sub><sup>***synonyms*** atrocity, disgrace, horror, obscenity, outrage, curse, torment, evil, crime, monstrosity, violation, bugbear, anathema, bane</sup></sub>

In my opinion, *bane* is an option, but it won't fit the OP's example perfectly

**Bane** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bane)

> *noun* 2. *archaic* Something, especially poison, which causes death.

Comment: "Nothing but a bane" sounds odd to me. It feels like it should be a bane *of something*, and all your examples also support that.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Thank you for the advice, how is my answer now? :)

Comment: Better, but you could explain the *bane* part more.

Answer (score 2):

**Scourge** - [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scourge)

> A person or thing that causes great trouble or suffering.

I also have heard **Cancer** used in this way. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cancer)

> Something bad or dangerous that causes other bad things to happen

I also agree with **Bane** but it was suggested already!

Comment: *Scourge* is a great word, but it's evil only in context. "A bullet is nothing but a scourge" could mean that justice is being served to unwholesome foes just as easily as it could mean that innocent people are getting mowed down. And I'd argue that it implies the former. *Cancer* is a good suggestion in that it implies something destructive and "anti-life" and negative.